# JSONArray null content Java & Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

It's possible that in an ArrayList it's not possible to put big content and then if you do it gives you null?

I'm inserting a JSONArray with 32 JSONObject each JSONObject has name and phone contact.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("something", content));


public void phoneandname(Context c) {

    if (cc.isOnline(c) == true) {
        db = new Database(c);

        Cursor phones = c.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
        db.open();

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            db.contact_table(name, phoneNumber);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {

                json.put("name", name);
                json.put("phone", phoneNumber);
                jarray.put(json);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        upload(jarray, context);

        db.close();

        Log.i("********", jarray.toString()); IT SHOWS MY ARRAY AND THEN BEFORE UPLOAD IT TO THE SERVER BY POST IT'S NULL...
        phones.close();
    }

}

public void upload(Object jobject, Context c) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    DBupload upload = new DBupload();
    DatosRegistro dr = new DatosRegistro(c);

    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", jobject.toString()));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", dr.hash_final(
            dr.token_secret(dr.mail(), "mail"), jobject.toString())));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(dr
            .return_id_phone())));

    JSONObject json2 = upload.UploaData(nvp,
            "http://anonyme.mariomontes.es/contacts/insert");

    try {
        if (json2.getInt("error") == 1) {

        } else {
            db.contact_table(name, phoneNumber);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also edit what the actual issue is? The code looks fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArraList<BasicNameValuePair>(); 
BasicNameValuePair tmp = new BasicNameValuePair("something", content);
nvp.add(tmp);
```

you have an `ArrayList` of `NameValuePair`. SO you need to put a `NameValuePair` object, inside the `ArrayList`

Comment: when i upload it to the server, the content request it's null... Maybe it's a size problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

THe only limit would be memory so far as I know.

I have some enormous JSONArray instances with much larger object inside.

I'm not sure what your code example relates to.

I would normally do something like this:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

//multiples of these
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("name","Marc");
jo.put("phone","1234567890");

ja.put(jo);
```

**UPDATE**

Ok I see what you mean now ... completely different question.

So the problem is more like to be that you are calling this:

`nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", jobject.toString()));`

but you are passing the JSONArray as an Object ... you need to cast it back to JSONArray

`nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content",((JSONArray)jobject).toString()));`

even better would be to pass the string to your upload function rather than as an object

Comment: Still not working... The server says that the petition was content=null :(

Comment: So are you passing it by string now?  If so, set a breakpoint and verify that your string contains what you think it contains before you send it.

Comment: ... then use fiddler2 to inspect the message when it arrives at the server

Comment: Yes, If you look at the code, just after upload I'm doing Log.i(); with the content and it shows perfectly what I want.

Comment: Try doing this inside the upload function for sanity check.  Did you download fiddler2 and see what it going out in the message?

Comment: Do you have a limit on the size you can upload?

Comment: No It's post petition so It's no limit i think